# How can I use jupyter notebook with binder and appmode?

Tags: android-binder

I want to create demo app by jupyter notebook and appmode and then would like to push to binder.
However, after pushing to binder, we can't use appmode in that notebook. Should I do anything special for that?

I tried to add 'environment.yml'

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - appmode
```

and 'postBuild'

```
#!/bin/bash

# Appmode Jupyter拡張機能のインストール
jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix appmode
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix appmode

# Appmodeの有効化
jupyter serverextension enable --py --sys-prefix appmode
```

and 'requirements.txt'

```
appmode
```

Comment: Because repos need to be public when using mybinder, it is easy to share them. So always include a link to the repo when asking for help about mybinder issues. It's a lot easier for those helping you to be able to test things. One issue I see is you are mixing and matching. Use `environment.yml` or `requirements.txt`. **Not both.** Your `postBuild` should look exactly like [here](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode/blob/master/binder/postBuild). Minor thing: this is tagged wrong; `android-binder` is completely different. Is there a `mybinder tag` or `binder` or `binderhub`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "after pushing to binder"? You push updates to a public repo/archive and then point mybinder.org at that public repository/archive.

Comment: Maybe most things are fine and you are running into [this issue](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode/issues/64)? Maybe not though? If that was the case, hopefully you would have described that clearly saying the error you see similar to the way the person describing the issue at that link described it. **There is a workaround for that if that is what is going on.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you ran into [this issue](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode/issues/64). A workaround to allow the appmode to work again at present without a '400: Bad Request' page is there. I've tested it in sessions launched via MyBinder and it presently enables appmode to work again.

You need to add a file named `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in the root of your repo. The contents of that file should be:

```py
c.ContentsManager.allow_hidden = True
```

I tested it already in conjunction with using a `binder` directory for the my binder configuration files. The `jupyter_notebook_config.py` stays in the root of the repo and **does NOT** belong inside the `binder` directory. (This is demonstrated [by this launch](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/test_json_appmode/9a1d16ec3953269e17a3d58d2b9ea579157f8aaa?urlpath=apps%2Findex.ipynb), which corresponds to [this particular commit of that repo with `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in root, in combination with a `binder` directory](https://github.com/fomightez/test_json_appmode/tree/9a1d16ec3953269e17a3d58d2b9ea579157f8aaa).)

Another test with `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in root and a `binder` directory is [here](https://github.com/fomightez/appmode_plus/). (Oddly, adding `vpython` as a pip installation breaks the fix; I don't understand this incompatibility, but I'm certain after quite a bit of testing it is an issue.)

---

I've implemented the same fix at these two, that don't involve a `binder` directory and I'm leaving them here as other examples of the fix:

- [my fork of the binder-examples/appmode repo](https://github.com/fomightez/appmode) (I've filed an issue to use this as model to fix the current binder-examples/appmode repo that presently also doesn't work because of [this issue](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode/issues/64).)
- [simple_appmode_binder](https://github.com/fomightez/simple_appmode_binder)

Comment: Hmmm...no appmode is working today, like a couple a week after.

Comment: Things will be fixed so appmode works via MyBinder launches again, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/mybinder-org-and-repo2docker-updates/18333/3?u=fomightez) and [here](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode/issues/64#issuecomment-1474123163) for current state.